# Giro shoe size help

Tags: shoes

Can someone help me with giro shoe size? Size guide say that half sized shoe are same length as full sized, is it true or just a mistake? https://www.giro.com/en/empire-acc/p/7041919

Comment: "Giro is currently updating its website. We'll be back soon." \*facepalm\* Dear Giro, you don't need to remove the old website until the new website is ready. That way, people can still use it to view your fine products and so on. You donkeys.

Comment: Did you ask Giro?

Comment: I sent them an email, but the did not reply. I got a screenshot of sizing chart https://imgur.com/a/zyXdYHC

Comment: Generally shoes in .5 (Half's) are 1/3inch different, the question should be are they bigger wider or longer ?

Comment: In my experience the sizing is inconsistent between different Giro models. That chart seems to be close to Rumble VR but the Alpineduro I tried runs much smaller.

Comment: I tried on a 43 size and it fit tight and snug, but i'm worry that my feet can swell up during long rides so maybe that 2,5mm will make difference. I think going full size up is too much

Comment: I'd guess that the cm measurements in the chart are rounded to nearest half cm, which is stupid but there you are.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably correct. The chart shows that there's only a 5mm difference in length between, e.g., a 43 and a 44, and a 43.5 is the same length as a 43. If a 43.5 was half-way between a 43 and a 44, there would only be a 2.5mm length difference between them, which is tiny: the exact thickness of your socks could easily make more difference than that.

Comment: I may have to respectfully disagree. I have had to check a lot of size charts recently. To the best of my knowledge, all the other companies with published size charts and half sizes will increment the last length with even a half size change. Giro could be an outlier. But it does seem more likely that they follow this trend, they just round their numbers.